# MYSQL insert in related tables

Tags: mysql

I have tables (few missed for shortness):

```
 CREATE TABLE `manufacturers` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `clocks` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`clock_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
`model_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`manufacturer_id` INT NOT NULL,
`cost` DOUBLE(10,2) NOT NULL,
`glass_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
`bracelet_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
`sex_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
`waterproof` boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
`mechanism_type_id` INT,
`touch_screen` boolean,
`telephone_communication` boolean,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`clock_type_id`) REFERENCES `clock_types`(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`glass_type_id`) REFERENCES `glass_types`(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`bracelet_type_id`) REFERENCES `bracelet_types`(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`sex_type_id`) REFERENCES `sex_types`(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (`mechanism_type_id`) REFERENCES `mechanism_types`(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturer_id`) REFERENCES `manufacturers`(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

How I can insert clock into database in one query, if i know only `manufacturer.name`, but not `manufacturer.id`? Rest data in proper form, so I have to put it in query as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDITED

Try [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement, something like this:

```
INSERT
INTO clocks
SELECT NULL, 1, 'rolex-test', m.id, 123.0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, null, null
FROM manufacturers AS m
WHERE m.name = 'rolex';
```

Comment: I got it but I have not understood how to write query for this. mysql show error on it. That is query: `INSERT INTO clocks (DEFAULT, 1, 'rolex-test', manufacturer_id, 123.0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, null, null)
SELECT m.id AS manufacturer_id
FROM manufacturers AS m
WHERE m.name = 'rolex';`